# Building JavaScript custom validators on the fly from my VB ASP.NET Code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, validation

I've got a bit of a weird question, and I haven't been able to find any threads online of people trying to do precisely the same thing.

Essentially, I have a 'Form Designer' which users can use to... design forms. They can select validation options on the fields and these options are picked up when the form is rendered and custom validators are added in the code.

Ideally, I'd like to generate these validators as strings of Javascript from within my .vb file. For example:

```
Dim clientValFunction As String = "function() {alert('in!'); if ("
For Each row As DataRow In RangesTable.Rows
    clientValFunction &= "(document.getelementbyid('<%=" & someControl  & ".ClientID%>').value" & " > " & row("ControlMinRange") _
        & " && document.getelementbyid('<%=" & someControl & ".ClientID%>').value" & " < " & someValue _
        & " && document.getelementbyid('<%=" & ATextBox(nTxt).ID & ".ClientID%>').value" & " > " & someValue _
        & " && document.getelementbyid('<%=" & ATextBox(nTxt).ID & ".ClientID%>').value" & " < " & someValue  & ") ||"

Next
clientValFunction &= "0) { alert('okay'); } else {alert('not okay'); return false;}}"
ACustomValidator(NCus).ClientValidationFunction = clientValFunction
```

Trouble is none of this code is seems to be activated when the form is submitted.

Does anyone have any idea why? Or how I might fix this problem.

If you need any more information please let me know.

Comment: You're already on the server, so putting server-side-interpreted code like `<%= %>` doesn't make a lot of sense. Just put the result into the script. Also, the name of the function is `document.getElementById()`; note the capitalization.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mike. I've tried making the change but no difference. You may notice there's an alert at the beginning of the constructed javascript function, which is not being called. This leads me to believe the javascript isn't being run at all.

Comment: I think that property is meant to be the name of a function, not the function code itself, but I'm not too familiar with the tech.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I used RegisterStartupScript to insert the javascript into the page, and then used the ClientValidationFunction property to call the javascript function I'd inserted, it now works perfectly :)